# Comparing NSDates in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, mkmapview, nsdate, swift2

I am making an app where the users make events that are visible as annotations on a map. I need the annotations to remove permanently once the current time is greater than the end time created by the user.  Right now the end time is given as a String then I compare it to the current time which I have converted into a String.  It always seems to work but once the several hours have gone by since the event was removed it always reappears.

Here is my current method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   //*********** Set up Time

    let date = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    let currentTimeString = formatter.stringFromDate(date)


    //Return Short Time String
    print("The time is \(currentTimeString)")



    //*********** Set up Map **************

    let lat = locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude
    let lon = locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude


    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.70, 0.70)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
    self.SpotterMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.EventMap.delegate = self;
    self.EventMap.showsUserLocation = true;


   print ("****** Welcome in MapViewController")


    let myGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: lat, longitude:lon)

    let radius = 40.0

    print ("****** this is my geoPoint from map view controller: \(myGeoPoint)")


    //MARK: *** let's look for Events ***

    var nearArray : [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []


        PFQuery(className: "EventInfo")
            .whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: myGeoPoint, withinMiles: radius)     //(474)
            .findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
                objects, error in
                if let proximityArray = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    //                        println("****** here the proximity matches: \(proximityArray)")
                    for near in proximityArray {
                        //                            println("here they are \(near)")

                        let position = near["spotlocation"] as? PFGeoPoint

                        let locLat = position?.latitude       //this is an optional
                        let locLong = position?.longitude     //this is an optional
                        let SlocLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locLat!, longitude: locLong!)

                        nearArray.append(SlocLocation)

                        if nearArray.isEmpty {
                            print ("*** ERROR! No Spots close by ***")
                        } else
                        {
                            for _ in nearArray {

                                let Start = near["starttime"] as! String
                                let End = near["endtime"] as! String
                                let Name = near["name"] as! String



                                let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.40, 0.40)
                                let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(SlocLocation, span)
                                self.EventMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

                                // Sets the values of the annotation
                                let Annotation = CustomPointAnnotation()
                                Annotation.coordinate = SlocLocation
                                Annotation.title = Name
                                Annotation.subtitle = Start + " - " + End
                                Annotation.imageName = "Annotation.png"





                                self.EventMap.addAnnotation(Annotation)




                                let endTime = End

                                print(currentTimeString)

                                let TimeStr = endTime
                                formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
                                let Time = formatter.dateFromString(TimeStr)

                                let dateFormater : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                                dateFormater.dateFormat = "h:mm ap"
                                let newTime = dateFormater.stringFromDate(Time!)
                                 print("\(currentTimeString) to \(newTime)")

                                if currentTimeString > newTime {



                                    self.EventMap.removeAnnotation(Annotation)
                                    print ("event removed")





                                }


                            }
                        }
                    }


                    }
                }
```

`

If someone could please help me that would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just keep them as NSDate objets and use NSDate.compare()? Converting NSDate to string and then comparing is kind of round about and is likely to just cause problems like you're seeing.

Comment: @MarkSponsler I have tried but it doesn't work because the user puts the end time in as the format "h:mm ap" so what I really need is a way to convert that short format to a format that is the full date.  How would I do that?

Comment: Does the event not have a date as well as a time?

Comment: @MarkSponsler I created an object for the "realendtime" in my Parse class as a Date but Im not sure how to make the time that is in the end time string a date.